# MS Access: average subset of records on report

Tags: ms-access

I have a database of test results with tables `students`, `tests` and `test_results`. Each record in `test_results` refers to a key from `students`, a key from `tests`, a score and a yes/no field for absent. I also have a report with subheadings (grouped by) for each test. I want to display the average score for each test on that test's heading but I only want to calculate the average over those records where the student was not absent.

I unsuccessfully tried two approaches:

1. A query named `averageScoreWhereNotAbsent` which is `SELECT Avg(score) AS Expr1 FROM test_results WHERE (((test_results.absent])=False));`; and an unbound field on the report's test grouping subheader, with source the expression `=DLookUp("[score]","[averageScoreWhereNotAbsent]![Expr1]","[test] = " & [ID])`. Unfortunately this returns '#error'. I tried tweaking it but it would ask me for parameters or would - oddly - display the score of the last student instead of the average. What's wrong with my syntax?!
2. Some VBA that loops through `test_results` looking for fields that match the current test ID and are not marked absent. It sums and averages them and updates an unbound field on the test subheader. The code is called when the report loads. It worked...but each test showed the same average. The problem was obvious :( in report view, the field is repeated every time the subheader is repeated i.e. for each test, but in design view you only see one subheader and one field - I don't know any way to refer to each subheader and field individually from VBA - I suppose it's all the same field!

I assume the answer is trivial but I'm new to Access - what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: How can an absent student take a test?

Comment: That was what I thought...but the school insisted that there be a distinction - they wanted to track those who should have been present. They have score 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to average by test, then add test as a group by variable in your aggregate query (of course adjust ID to actual field name that indicates test):

```
SELECT test_ID, Avg(score) AS AverageScore
FROM test_results 
WHERE (((test_results.[absent])=False))
GROUP BY test_ID;
```

Then the [DLookUp](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/domain/dlookup.php) on report would look like the following (of course adjust report names and test_ID control to their actual names and be sure control exists in section it is placed):

```
=DLookUp("[AverageScore]","[averageScoreWhereNotAbsent]",
         "[test_ID] = " & Reports!reportname!test_IDfield)
```

Comment: Thanks! - looks great but will have to wait for the morning to try it to confirm...will let you know!

Comment: Wow, amazing! Thanks. I marked as answer but don't have enough reputation for you to see my upvote. 1 typo though: you left a '[ ' out of `(((test_results.absent])=False))` - happens to the best of us.